# How did Black Panther win his last battle?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

During the finale of *Black Panther*, when T'Challa is fighting on the train tracks and manages to put a spear in Eric Killmonger, I didn't quite get the trick with powers off powers on that T'Challa did.

What happened there and how exactly did he win this fight?

Comment: Also, don't forget that when he lost to Killmonger, he had the upper hand a couple times during the fight, but refused to kill his opponent. At the end, he was devoid of the sentiment and fought full-on.

Answer (score 7):

The train tracks were destabilizing the vibranium armor/suit both of them were wearing.  This was getting constantly activated on and off when the train would go by. T'Challa waited for the time when the track was just enabled and Killmonger was there to be able to stab him since his suit wasn't able to deflect the knife.

Comment: Throughout the fight, you can see that the sonic destabilizers cause their Panther suits to waver in places, i.e. leave gaps in what they protect. T’Challa happened to stab Erik in a spot where the suit wasn’t currently functional. In addition, when the full functions of the suit came back, presumably it held the spearhead in place which essentially kept Erik alive while it remained there.

Comment: I understood the idea of it, but not exactly the flow of things.